# How to set Visibility.Collapsed as Tag's value

Tags: wpf

I need a listbox to store 'Visible' or 'Collapsed' enum value in its 'Tag' property, something like:

```
<ListBox Tag="{x: ... Visible}"/>
```

How can I make that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ListBox xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationCore"               
         Tag="{x:Static wpf:Visibility.Visible}"/>
```